# SELE command with #2 && Name

Tags: visual-foxpro

```
Sele 2 && Conductor
```

I am asked to convert a Visual Fox Pro app to Asp.NET Core

I am having trouble finding out what this means.

Answer (score 4):

In FoxPro, commands can optionally get four-letter abbreviated.
So that `Sele` is a lazy way to refer to the `Select` command and `&& Conductor` is a code editor comment, similar to a hypothetical C# line like:

```
Select 2; // Conductor
```

Quoted from

> Visual FoxPro 9.0 SP2  Help
> SELECT Command

Activates the specified work area.
SELECT nWorkArea | cTableAlias

Parameters
nWorkArea
Specifies a work area to activate. If nWorkArea is 0, the lowest-numbered unused work area is activated.

cTableAlias
Specifies a work area containing an open table to activate. cTableAlias is the alias of the open table. You can also include a letter from A through J for cTableAlias to activate one of the first ten work areas.