# Sum by group in foxpro

Tags: sum, foxpro

I'm newbie in foxpro programming. i have some issue how to fill "sum value" column with value data from second column by id_doc from first column. Thankyou

From this
[table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORqvX.png)

```
Table1
Id_doc   Value   Sum_Value
AA       12      ??
AA       11      ??
AA       14      ??
BB       9       ?? 
BB       8       ??
CC       7       ??
CC       10      ??
CC       13      ??
```

To This Table
[Table results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrtWy.png)

I have try this

```sql
  SELECT id_doc, SUM(NILAI) as Jml; 
  FROM table2;
  GROUP BY Id_doc;
  
  INNER JOIN Jml_nilai as Jml ;
  ON Id_doc = Id_doc;
  ORDER BY Id_doc ASCENDING;
```

But it's not running well....

Comment: Please add a few `Create Cursor` and `Insert Into` statements to show your Data Structure (Types) as well as the Content of "table2" as well as "Jml_nilai", and also the one of "table1" as a Text rather than a picture, and also a description of the expected result

Comment: What do you mean when you say _"it's not running well"_, do you get Errors?

Comment: Are you trying to get a running total per ID as each entry is getting processed?  Or, are you just trying to get the single ID_Doc and their respective total.  If you are trying to get some name from a secondary table `jml_nilai`, you are not showing the context of the second table and suggest you EDIT your existing question and add the details.

Comment: Your new description sounds as if the expected result is only three rows `GROUP BY id_doc` so to say right? See also the edited Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your current description looks as if you want this:

```
CREATE CURSOR table1 (id_doc Char(20), value Int, sum_value Int)
INSERT INTO table1 (id_doc, value) VALUES ('AA', 12)
INSERT INTO table1 (id_doc, value) VALUES ('AA', 11)
INSERT INTO table1 (id_doc, value) VALUES ('AA', 14)
INSERT INTO table1 (id_doc, value) VALUES ('BB', 9)
INSERT INTO table1 (id_doc, value) VALUES ('BB', 8)
INSERT INTO table1 (id_doc, value) VALUES ('BB', 7)
INSERT INTO table1 (id_doc, value) VALUES ('CC', 7)
INSERT INTO table1 (id_doc, value) VALUES ('CC', 10)
INSERT INTO table1 (id_doc, value) VALUES ('CC', 13)

SELECT id_doc, SUM(value) FROM table1 GROUP BY id_doc
```

**Edited:** This could be the "running group sums self-Join" SQL as mentioned in the currently last comment:

```
SELECT T1.id_doc, T1.value, T2.grpSum FROM table1 T1 ;
    JOIN (SELECT id_doc, SUM(value) as grpSum FROM table1 GROUP BY id_doc) T2 ;
        On T2.id_doc = T1.id_doc
```

Later: learned that it's rather called `[groupwise-maximum]`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/groupwise-maximum

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry if the question asked confuses you.
For that I sent the picture before (problem) and the second picture is the last desired condition.

Comment: And the _INNER JOIN Jml_nilai as Jml_ is obsolete?

Comment: INNER JOIN is not absolute

Comment: Not absolute? Or *obsolete?, then if you are actually looking for a "running totals" or a "running group sums" column perhaps, both can be done via `Self Join`, i.e you would Join your so called "table1" with itself, where the former would be relatively "expensive" from a performance point-of-view and the latter would be a little "cheaper". In `foxpro`  and even more in `visual-foxpro` you would have quiet rich UI/Window/Form features, so that you would not necessarily need to go the expensive way. After web-searching the previously mentioned terms, which one would you prefer?

Answer (score -1):

Thank you so much for all response. Finally it's done....

Sharing for all. This is what i did.

```
CLOSE all
SET SAFETY OFF 

******************************************************************


USE table1.dbf 
INDEX on id_doc TO a
TOTAL ON id_doc TO table1_jumlah.dbf

CLOSE ALL 
*************************************************************

sele 1
* data primer (master)
    use table1_jumlah.dbf
    index on id_doc to i


sele 2
* data sekunder (diisi)
    use table1.dbf
    index on id_doc to ii


sele 1
go top
do while .not. eof()
    iddocx=Id_doc
    valuex=Value
    
    sele 2
      loca for id_doc=iddocx
      if found()
        repl ALL Sum_Value with Valuex for id_doc=iddocx 
    endi

   sele 1
   skip
   loop
endd

**********************************************************

CLOSE ALL
DELETE FILE *.bak
DELETE FILE *.idx
```

Comment: I down-voted the reply because it contains a lot of not so recommendable things.
Like sele 1, sele 2, sele 3 anonymous work-area numbers instead of self-explainig alias _names_, and another reader or even yourself in few years would perhaps not know that you meant the `SELECT` (full-name) command. `Close All` would affect all objects, Forms, Opened Databases, private Data Sessions etc., the entire app environment, rather than just that in-sight handful of work-area aliases that you just had opened.

Comment: You can tell "run-time" from "maintenance" time by having separate binaries for separate purposes. When you do not, you would need to fix bugs on either side in the same binary code file, so that the entire your.App.EXE could possibly fall back into "beta" status in a case that would affect only a few among all your users

Comment: You can create Index `Tags` in a "compound index (*.CDX) file" at design-time (see also the INDEX command in Help), as opposed to wasting performance resources at run-time

Comment: And the `SCAN`/`ENDSCAN` loop is safer than "do while .not. eof()". And for xBase commands and functions that have an "ALIAS" parameter, you could take advantage of that concept, e.g. with eof(), found(), go top, sele , repl, and so on, so that not so many 'unexpected' aliases can get affected

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71148803/sele-command-with-2-name